# How did kusama and Polkadot integrated their respective ledger nano app via Polkadot ui?

Tags: polkadot-js, polkadot, kusama, ledger

Polkadot and kusama respectively have integrated their platform with [ledger hardware wallet](https://www.ledger.com/). After reading documentation I came to know that integrating a blockchain with ledger requires a nano app which will run in ledger and a GUI. Kusama and polkadot prepared their respective nano app and for GUI they used [Polkadot UI](https://polkadot.js.org/apps/?rpc=wss%3A%2F%2Frpc.polkadot.io#/settings) to connect ledger and perform operations such as transfer and staking as seen on this [link](https://support.ledger.com/hc/en-us/articles/4416512532625-Set-up-and-use-polkadot-js-to-access-your-Ledger-Kusama-KSM-account?docs=true). My question is can other substrate based app use Polkadot-UI for connecting ledger and perform operation like Kusama and polkadot. If yes then how can I do that?